# Selenium no another page

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am scraping one page but the problem i came up today was that the page didn`t have another page and it gave me the previous page without any error from which i could determine that page was last one..

for ex: https://example/page-7
when i want to go to: https://example/page-8 which doesn`t exist it gives me
the last page: https://example/page-7

How could i determine that https://example/page-7 was the last page using python3???

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

page = "https://www.supermama.lt/forumas/topic/214375-vilma/page-1"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(page)
dd = driver.page_source

for j in range(100):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(dd, "html.parser")
    my_text = list(soup.findAll("div", class_ = "post-content"))
    for i in my_text:
        #collect some data
        pass

    page = "https://www.supermama.lt/forumas/topic/214375-vilma/page{0}".format(j+2)
    driver.get(page)
    dd = driver.page_source
```

At first i was thinking about checking dublicates of collected data but this is too slow cause i have 30 000 links from which i have to collect data. Maybe there is easier solution??

Comment: Please post some of your code attempts first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question. 
To find the page url just use driver.current_url

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

page = "https://www.supermama.lt/forumas/topic/214375-vilma/"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(page)

dd = driver.page_source

current_pages = [] 

for j in range(100):

    page_url = driver.current_url

    if(page_url not in current_pages):
        current_pages.append(page_url)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(dd, "html.parser")
        my_text = list(soup.findAll("div", class_ = "post-content"))
        for i in my_text:
            #collect some data
            pass

        page = "https://www.supermama.lt/forumas/topic/214375-vilma/page-{0}".format(j+2)
        driver.get(page)
        dd = driver.page_source

    else:
        print(current_pages)
        driver.quit()
        break
```